# C++ - Vector initialization failing

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, infinity

I'm attempting to initialize a multi-dimensional vector with:

```
vector<double> v0(point_list.size(), numeric_limits<double>::max);
vector<vector<double> > v1(point_list.size(),v0);
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<double>::vector(std::vector<std::vector<int> >::size_type, double (&)()throw ())’
```

Can anyone explain this to me and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numeric_limits<double>::max` is a function.  You wanted to say:

```
vector<double> v0(point_list.size(), numeric_limits<double>::max());
```